# How to change font, fontweight, colormap ... in matplotlib plots consistently and easily for scientific papers?

Tags: matplotlib, fonts, colormap

Below are what I have found the most convenient way so far of setting these parameters consistently for all plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'jet'
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Arial'
plt.rcParams['font.weight'] = 'bold
```

Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
font = {'cmap' : 'jet',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'family'   : 'Arial'}

plt.rcParams('font', **font)
```

For more details you can refer https://matplotlib.org/api/matplotlib_configuration_api.html#matplotlib.rc